# How to write test class for below method

Tags: unit-test

```
public class MyContactListController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id recordId) {
       return [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone From Contact Where AccountId = :recordId];
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is one of the simplest unit tests you can write - just insert your test data and validate that the return value is what's expected. Have you worked through the Trailhead module on testing Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first insert contact and account records before calling controller methods.

```
@isTest
private class MyContactListControllerTest {
   static testMethod void testMethod1 (){
       Account testAcc = new Account( Name = 'TestAccount' ); //Specify desired record type and all required fields if any
       INSERT testAcc;

       Contact testCon = new Contact( FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Contact', AccountId = testAcc.Id, Email = 'test@test.com' ); //Specify desired record type and all required fields if any
       INSERT testCon;

       System.assertEquals(MyContactListController.getContacts(testAcc.Id).size(),1); //Assert statement to verify the result
   }
}
```

Please try out trialhead for [Apex unit test](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro).